# Edited: Hide a userprofile property from sharepoint 2010 powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-property

**EDIT**

I have a created the property now using below url. now I want to assign a custom subtype to the section property and the existing property by using powershell. Any inputs?

```
 // Take list of Property Names and Remove them from a ProfileSubtype 
public void RemovePropertiesFromProfileSubtypePropertyGroup(string subtypeName, List<string> properties, SPSite site) 
{ 
foreach (string property in properties) 
 { 
 SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site); 
UserProfileManager _userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
ProfileSubtypePropertyManager _profileSubtypePropertyManager = _userProfileManager.DefaultProfileSubtypeProperties; 
ProfileSubtypeProperty sProperty = _profileSubtypePropertyManager.GetPropertyByName(property); 

 if (sProperty == null) 
sProperty = _profileSubtypePropertyManager.GetSectionByName(property); 

RemovePropertyToSubtype(subtypeName, sProperty, serviceContext); 
} 
} 
// Remove property from a SubType 
private void RemovePropertyToSubtype(string subtypeName, ProfileSubtypeProperty property, SPServiceContext serviceContext) 
{ 
ProfileSubtypeManager _profileSubtypeManager = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(serviceContext); 
foreach (ProfileSubtype subtype in _profileSubtypeManager.GetSubtypesForProfileType(ProfileType.User)) 
{ 
if (subtype.Name.Equals(subtypeName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
{ 
if (subtype.Properties.GetPropertyByName(property.Name) != null || subtype.Properties.GetSectionByName(property.Name) != null) 
{ 
if (property.IsSection) 
subtype.Properties.RemoveSectionByName(property.Name); 
  else 
subtype.Properties.RemovePropertyByName(property.Name); 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: What error? Are you a UPA Admin?

Comment: Actually, first time when i execute the script, no error comes, but then Section property is not added if i check in Manage User Property. And when the script is executed second time then the error comes "Duplicate property cannot be added"

Comment: Is the section visible? What happens when you enumerate the sections with PoSh, do you see the new section?

Comment: ok I did that using this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3657786-8166-4a63-b998-911458f271d6/how-to-add-user-profile-property-sections-with-powershell?forum=sharepointadminprevious. Now I want to add a subtype to the already created property. Any inputs how to do that in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the use of user profile subtypes and organizations. Neither was fully implemented and the support for subtypes is weak.

Comment: yes, even on internet there is so less the info for the same. But I got some bits of code in c#  but I am facing issues converting it to powershell. Updating the c# code in question. Could you help me in this?

Comment: Like I said, I avoid using subtypes. What is your use case? How do you plan to use them?

Comment: I have to add a new section and a property. Also I have to hide 2 sections and some properties. When i create a new subtype, it is automatically assigned to the existing properties. If we remove the "Default User profile subtype" from the properties to be removed; they will be hidden. So I am trying to remove the subtype from the existing properties.

Comment: No, I mean what are you using the subtype for? If you just need to hide properties you don't need subtypes.

Comment: Is there any other way to hide properties using powershell?

Comment: Are you just hiding them from the end user who is editing their profile?

Comment: You can change the Visibility and Edit-ability using IsVisibleOnEditor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.profiletypeproperty.isvisibleoneditor.aspx

Comment: Thanks Matthew. It worked. I am writing an answer with the working code

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for hiding a property

```
##########CODE########################
# Load SharePoint.PowerShell snapin 
if (!(Get-PSSnapin | ?{$_.name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'})) 
{ 
    if(Get-PSSnapin -registered | ?{$_.name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'}) 
    { 
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
        write-host "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell in session" 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        write-host "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is not registered with the system." 
        break 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    write-host "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is already loaded" 
} 
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$logcsv = $ScriptPath + "\HideProperty.csv"     #output csv format
Set-Content -Path $logcsv -Value $header -Encoding UTF8
#Function to get service context
function Get-SPServiceContext([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication] $profileApp)
{
    $profileApp = @(Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application"})[0]
return [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($profileApp.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier]::Default)
}

$stackTrace = ""

try{
####Get UserProfileManager
$stackTrace = "Error in: User Profile Objects"
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext
$userProfileConfigManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($serviceContext)
$userProfilePropertyManager = $userProfileConfigManager.ProfilePropertyManager
$userProfileTypeProperties = $userProfilePropertyManager.GetProfileTypeProperties([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)
$corePropertyManager = $userProfilePropertyManager.GetCoreProperties()
$userProfileSubTypeManager = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubTypeManager]::Get($serviceContext)
$userProfile = $userProfileSubTypeManager.GetProfileSubtype([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeManager]::GetDefaultProfileName([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User))
$userProfileProperties = $userProfile.Properties 

Write-Host "User Profile Objects setup complete"

Write-Host "Updating Properties..."


####Set Core Property values
$stackTrace += "Error in: Core Property"

$PropertyName = "EmailVersion"
$coreProperty = $userProfileProperties.GetPropertyByName($PropertyName)

#### Add Profile Type Property
$stackTrace += "Error in: Profile Type Property"
Write-Host "Changing Profile Type Property settings"
$profileTypeProperty = $userProfileTypeProperties.GetPropertyByName($coreProperty.Name)
if($profileTypeProperty ){
Write-Host "Updating... profileType Property: " $PropertyName
$profileTypeProperty.IsVisibleOnEditor = $IsPropertyIsVisibleOnEditor
$profileTypeProperty.Commit()
}
else{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Property: " $PropertyName  " does'nt exist."
    $PropertyName + " does'nt exist."  | Add-Content -Path $logcsv      
}


catch{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Source
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.StackTrace
$_.Exception.Source + ";"+ $_.Exception.Message +";" + $_.Exception.StackTrace  | Add-Content -Path $logcsv
}

 ##################################
```